# Why is heroku post-build appending `/app` to my start script file?

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy and applicaiton via Heroku, and am using the `heroku-postbuild` command in my `package.json` file to do this.

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "article-ranker-v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js --prefix backend",
    "heroku-postbuild": "set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false&&npm install --prefix backend&&npm install --prefix frontend&&npm run build --prefix frontend",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "server:dev": "npm run start:dev --prefix backend",
    "client:dev": "npm run start:dev --prefix frontend",
    "server:prod": "npm run start:prod --prefix backend",
    "client:prod": "npm run start:prod --prefix frontend",
    "server:debug": "npm run debug --prefix backend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server:dev\" \"npm run client:dev\"",
    "debug": "concurrently \"npm run server:debug\" \"npm run client:dev\"",
    "prod": "concurrently \"npm run server:prod\" \"npm run client:prod\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",

}
```

Strangely, i am getting the following error when i run `heroku-logs`:

```
2021-03-27T11:30:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-03-27T11:30:12.045477+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-27T11:30:22.109846+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-03-27T11:30:24.585408+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-27T11:30:24.585423+00:00 app[web.1]: > article-ranker-v2@1.0.0 start /app
2021-03-27T11:30:24.585424+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js --prefix backend
2021-03-27T11:30:24.585424+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-27T11:30:24.639473+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
2021-03-27T11:30:24.639474+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-03-27T11:30:24.639475+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-03-27T11:30:24.639475+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-03-27T11:30:24.639476+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
2021-03-27T11:30:24.639477+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
```

The issue appears to be that it is trying to find my `server.js` file inside an `app` folder; however, no such folder exists - the `server.js` file is in the root of the `backend` folder.

Anyone know why the path is being pre-pended with `/app`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I found that my `server.js` file was somehow not included in the repo. Adding it to the repo manually fixed the issue. I think heroku does in fact have all the files within an `app` folder.